# Click a button Appium C#

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I've created some unit tests and I'm using Appium to run these tests. I want to be able to click a button and typically I can use the FindElementByName property however in this case I can't as there are 2 elements that have the same name.

Below is an image of the properties I can see when I use inspector.

[image]

```
PowerPointSession.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        PowerPointSession.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[contains(text(), 'Open') or contains(text(), 'open')]")).Click();
```

I also tried

```
PowerPointSession.FindElementByName("Open").Click();
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing a work around and just done this

```
PowerPointSession.Keyboard.SendKeys(Keys.Enter);
```

Done the trick